# validate two data frames on the basis on one column

Tags: r

I am trying to validate two data frames if the same same id have different city. the out required is the data in first data frame and one mutated column.

do we have any other solution...??

df data frame should be as it is one added one mutated column.

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2251","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2923","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal","singh,nkunj","garg","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


dfj <- full_join(df, df1, by = "ID", suffix = c("1", "2"), keep = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(same_city = (city1 == city2) %>% replace_na(FALSE),
         missing2 = is.na(ID2))
```

so it should lookup df$ID in df1$ID , if df$ID present in df1$ID then check if city is same , if city is different the mutate new column as "different city"

output should like below

[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to accomplish. Is `dfj` not what you need? how should it be different? If you provide a little example of your desired results could be quite helpful.

Comment: I have updated my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

```r
out <- merge(df, subset(df1, select=-Name), by="ID", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y"))
out$same_city <- !is.na(out$city.y) & out$city == out$city.y
out
#         ID city           Name city.y same_city
# 1           MUM       ali,sanu    MUM      TRUE
# 2  ANA2548  del   tomar,lakhan    del      TRUE
# 3  ANA2719  DEL   abbas,salman    DEL      TRUE
# 4  ANA2813  DEL    pawar,pooja    DEL      TRUE
# 5  DEV2698  DEL    singh,nkunj    DEL      TRUE
# 6  DEV2732  mum     ali,sarman    mum      TRUE
# 7  DEV2962  DEL      dev,akash    DEL      TRUE
# 8  ERV2951  mum  singh,giriraj    mum      TRUE
# 9  HRT2837  mum     khan,zuber    mum      TRUE
# 10 HRT2921  del    garg,prabal   <NA>     FALSE
# 11 ITI2210  DEL  sharma,nikita    DEL      TRUE
# 12 ITI2535  MUM thakur,praveen    MUM      TRUE
# 13 ITI2624  MUM        lal,ram    MUM      TRUE
# 14 KTN2252  mum    singh,rahul   <NA>     FALSE
# 15 KTN2542  mum  sharma,lokesh    mum      TRUE
# 16 KTN2624  DEL    singh,kunal    DEL      TRUE
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
select(df1, -Name) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "ID", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(same_city = !is.na(city.y) & city == city.y)
#         ID city           Name city.y same_city
# 1  DEV2962  DEL      dev,akash    DEL      TRUE
# 2  KTN2252  mum    singh,rahul   <NA>     FALSE
# 3  ANA2719  DEL   abbas,salman    DEL      TRUE
# 4  ITI2624  MUM        lal,ram    MUM      TRUE
# 5  DEV2698  DEL    singh,nkunj    DEL      TRUE
# 6  HRT2921  del    garg,prabal   <NA>     FALSE
# 7           MUM       ali,sanu    MUM      TRUE
# 8  KTN2624  DEL    singh,kunal    DEL      TRUE
# 9  ANA2548  del   tomar,lakhan    del      TRUE
# 10 ITI2535  MUM thakur,praveen    MUM      TRUE
# 11 DEV2732  mum     ali,sarman    mum      TRUE
# 12 HRT2837  mum     khan,zuber    mum      TRUE
# 13 ERV2951  mum  singh,giriraj    mum      TRUE
# 14 KTN2542  mum  sharma,lokesh    mum      TRUE
# 15 ANA2813  DEL    pawar,pooja    DEL      TRUE
# 16 ITI2210  DEL  sharma,nikita    DEL      TRUE
```